# Excel VBA returning "Compile error: Expected: expression"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to set a value to the return value of another function, but am getting stuck on this line:

```
Set tempMergeValue = TypeRegxFunc(MyRange.Rows(iCounter).Columns(1).Value,'([^.]+)')
```

The TypeRegxFunc is here

```
Function TypeRegxFunc(strInput As String, regexPattern As String) As String
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = regexPattern
    End With

    If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
        Set matches = regEx.Execute(strInput)
        TypeRegxFunc = matches(0).Value
    Else
        TypeRegxFunc = "not matched"
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Replace the apostrophes round the regex pattern with quotation marks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to replace apostrophes `''` with quotation marks `""`, otherwise VBA will interpret that as a comment.

Change this line:

```
Set tempMergeValue = TypeRegxFunc(MyRange.Rows(iCounter).Columns(1).Value,'([^.]+)')
```

With this one:

```
Set tempMergeValue = TypeRegxFunc(MyRange.Rows(iCounter).Columns(1).Value,"([^.]+)")
```

And it will work.

I hope this helps.